# How to can i solve "adapter cannot be applied" error?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-adapter

**Hi everyone, can you guys help me with this "adapter cannot be applied" error? I was trying to display my data from the SQLite Database. I am new to android studio and I hope you all can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance!**

```
public class profile extends Fragment {
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
        ArrayList<String> listItem;
        ArrayAdapter adapter;
        ListView userlist;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container, false);
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        userlist = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_list);
        listItem = new ArrayList<>();
        viewData();

        userlist.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                SQLiteCursor cursor = (SQLiteCursor) userlist.getItemAtPosition(position);
                cursor.getString(6);
                cursor.getString(0);
                cursor.getString(1);
                cursor.getString(2);
                cursor.getString(3);
                cursor.getString(4);
                cursor.getString(5);


            }
        });

    }

    private void viewData() {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.viewData();

        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Data Show!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(0));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(1));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(2));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(3));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(4));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(5));
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(6));

            }
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItem);
            userlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the import of the ListView, it should look like this- import android.widget.ListView